# Way to define cakephp inputDefaults at site level

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

Is there a way to define `options['inputDefaults']` at site level than that at each form

Comment: +1 - always thought about doing that, but never got around to looking how.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**TLDR:**

Paste the 2 chunks of code below in their respective spots, then change the `$defaultOptions` array to whatever you want - voila.  It doesn't alter any of the FormHelper's functions except adds defaults to the `Form->create`'s `inputDefaults`.

**Explanation & Code:**

You can extend the FormHelper (easier than it sounds) by making your own custom `MyFormHelper`:

```
<?php
//create this file called 'MyFormHelper.php' in your View/Helper folder
App::uses('FormHelper', 'View/Helper');
class MyFormHelper extends FormHelper {

    public function create($model = null, $options = array()) {
        $defaultOptions = array(
            'inputDefaults' => array(
                'div' => false,
                'label' => false
            )
        );      

        if(!empty($options['inputDefaults'])) {
            $options = array_merge($defaultOptions['inputDefaults'], $options['inputDefaults']);
        } else {
            $options = array_merge($defaultOptions, $options);
        }
        return parent::create($model, $options);
    }
}
```

Then, in your AppController, include the Form helper in the following way (if you already have a $helpers variable, just add `'Form' => ...` to it):

```
public $helpers = array(
    'Form' => array(
        'className' => 'MyForm'
    )
);
```

This makes it so whenever you call `$this->Form`, it actually calls your custom 'MyFormHelper' - and the only thing it does is set the `inputDefaults` if they're not specified, then continue on to do the normal logic found in Cake's FormHelper.

Answer (score 0):

This is really great - I did change this a bit, so that you use Hash::merge, instead of array merge to keep it to the Cake Api. Also, I named mine "AppFormHelper" - but that is just my own naming: naming helpers is pretty loose. Thanks for the tip!

Hash Class: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/hash.html

```
<?php
/**
 * @file AppFormHelper.
 *  This allows you to create defaults for your forms.
 */
App::uses('FormHelper', 'View/Helper');

class AppFormHelper extends FormHelper {

  public function create($model = null, $options = array()) {
    $default = array(
      'inputDefaults' => array(
        'div' => false,
        'class' => 'form-control',
        'autocomplete' => 'off',
      ),
    );
    $options = Hash::merge($default, $options);
    return parent::create($model, $options);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can I please add that Dave's code above has a bug in it. The line:

```
$options = array_merge($defaultOptions['inputDefaults'], $options['inputDefaults']);
```

Causes a "Notice (8): Array to string conversion [CORE/Cake/View/Helper.php, line 486]" when inputDefaults is specified in both the the extended FormHelper as well as in the form itself.

This bug is not present in kirikintha's version.